# Reading data from a file in vertical "blocks" in C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

Let me first show you the structure of the data I'm reading (it will be hard to convey what I want otherwise):

```
 Mode:                 1                      2                      3
 Frequency:      -307.68                  57.11                  82.39
 Force Cnst:      0.6182                 0.0089                 0.0283
 Red. Mass:      11.0830                 4.6138                 7.0866
 IR Active:          YES                    YES                    YES
 IR Intens:       17.343                  7.786                  0.017
 Raman Active:       YES                    YES                    YES
               X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
 H         -0.093 -0.046 -0.050    0.002 -0.268  0.324   -0.084 -0.209  0.128
 C         -0.072 -0.019 -0.063    0.003 -0.159  0.195   -0.048 -0.148  0.087
 C         -0.001 -0.046 -0.072    0.007 -0.001  0.001   -0.001 -0.229  0.139
 H         -0.001 -0.120 -0.089    0.006 -0.001  0.001   -0.001 -0.345  0.213
 C          0.073 -0.023 -0.057    0.003  0.158 -0.194    0.047 -0.151  0.090
 H          0.096 -0.052 -0.043    0.002  0.266 -0.322    0.083 -0.214  0.134
 ............................................................................
```

So, I want to store the data for each Mode under its own struct object (nmode), and store each nmode in a vector. However, as you can see, the data for each Mode is output in this vertical formatting (I cannot change the format of this file).

Currently, my workaround solution has been to tell the program to get the data for three Modes at once, using ifstream as normal (I'll post an example of this below). This solution breaks on any number of Modes not divisible by 3, for obvious reasons. My question is therefore "what is the best way for me to have the program read this data from these vertical blocks for an arbitrary number of Modes?"

Here is the current solution (that breaks if the number of Modes is not divisible by 3), as well as a case on which it breaks:

```
ifstream ifile
nmode mode_1; 
nmode mode_2;
nmode mode_3;
std::cout << "Getting normal mode numbers..." << std::endl;
                    
ifile >> mode_1.mode;
ifile >> mode_2.mode;
ifile >> mode_3.mode;
ifile >> trash; 
std::cout << "Getting normal mode frequencies..." << std::endl;
ifile >> mode_1.freq;
ifile >> mode_2.freq;
ifile >> mode_3.freq;

etc.
```

```
EXAMPLE THAT BREAKS ABOVE CODE

 Mode:                 1
 Frequency:      2670.34
 Force Cnst:     58.8309
 Red. Mass:      14.0031
 IR Active:          YES
 IR Intens:        0.000
 Raman Active:       YES
               X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
 N         -0.000 -0.000 -0.707
 N          0.000  0.000  0.707
```

Comment: Instead of three numbered `mode_` variables, consider an array or `std::vector`. That way you can have a `for` loop that reads into 0 to N `nmode`s. This will make your life much easier.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn’t clear—the nmodes ARE being added to a std::vector. The reason I’m doing this clunky “three mode variables” setup is because the data I want for each nmode is organized in tabular form, so I can’t easily read in one node at a time since the ifstream object proceeds left-to-right, line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no quick answer.

You really need to parse line by line . . .

This will result in a lot of code. YOuld be optimzed by writing functions to parse similar line. But le's go with the full approach here:

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std::string_literals;

// Definition of data structures
struct XYZ {
    char Indicator{};
    double x{};
    double y{};
    double z{};
};

struct Data {
    std::size_t ID{};
    double frequency{};
    double forceCnst{};
    double redMass{};
    bool irActive{};
    double irIntensity{};
    bool ramanActive{};
    std::vector<XYZ> xyz{};
};
// Function to read data in given format
std::vector<Data> readData(std::istream& is) {

    bool parsingOKsoFar{true};

    // Here we will store the resuting values 
    std::vector<Data> data{};

    // First read the modes -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; std::getline(is>>std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "Mode"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the first line to get information about number of modes
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read and with that count the number of modes
        std::vector<std::size_t> modeIDs{};
        for (size_t m; iss >> m; modeIDs.push_back(m))
            ;
        // Now, we know the number of Modes. Resize the resulting vector accordingly
        data.resize(modeIDs.size());

        // Copy mode IDs into structs
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
            data[i].ID = modeIDs[i];
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Mode could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read frequencies -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "Frequency"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<double> frequency{};
        for (double f{}; iss >> f; frequency.push_back(f));

        // Sanity check
        if (frequency.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].frequency = frequency[i];
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of frequencies and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Frequency could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read force constants -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "Force Cnst"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<double> forceConst{};
        for (double f{}; iss >> f; forceConst.push_back(f));

        // Sanity check
        if (forceConst.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].forceCnst = forceConst[i];
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of force constant and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Force Constant could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read red mass -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "Red. Mass"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<double> redMass{};
        for (double rm{}; iss >> rm; redMass.push_back(rm));

        // Sanity check
        if (redMass.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].redMass = redMass[i];
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of Red Rass and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Red Mass could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read IR Active -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "IR Active"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<std::string> irActive{};
        for (std::string ira{}; iss >> ira; irActive.push_back(ira));

        // Sanity check
        if (irActive.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].irActive = (irActive[i]=="YES"s) ? true : false;
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of IR Active and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: IR Active could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read IR Intensity -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "IR Intens"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<double> irIntens{};
        for (double irt{}; iss >> irt; irIntens.push_back(irt));

        // Sanity check
        if (irIntens.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].irIntensity = irIntens[i];
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of IR intensity and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: IR intensity could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read Raman Active -------------------------------------------------------
    if (std::string id{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is >> std::ws, id, ':') and (id == "Raman Active"s)) {

        // Read the rest of the line to get information about frequencies
        std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream iss{ line };

        // Read the values
        std::vector<std::string> ramanActive{};
        for (std::string ra{}; iss >> ra; ramanActive.push_back(ra));

        // Sanity check
        if (ramanActive.size() == data.size())

            // Copy into structs
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i)
                data[i].ramanActive = (ramanActive[i] == "YES"s) ? true : false;
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of Raman Active and modes\n\n";
            parsingOKsoFar = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Raman Active could not be read\n\n";
        parsingOKsoFar = false;
    }

    // Now read XYZ header line and throw away -------------------------------------------------------
    if (parsingOKsoFar) {
        std::string line{};
        parsingOKsoFar = !!std::getline(is, line);
    }
    // Read xyz data-------------------------------------------------------
    // Read all lines until we find a "....." pattern
    
    for (std::string line{}; parsingOKsoFar and std::getline(is, line) and (line.substr(0, 5) != "....."s);) {

        // End condition for reading the file
        if (line.substr(1, 5) == "....."s) break;

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        // First read indicator
        if (char indicator{}; iss >> indicator) {

            std::vector<XYZ> xyz{};
            for (XYZ tmp{}; iss >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> tmp.z; xyz.push_back(tmp));

            // Sanity check
            if (xyz.size() == data.size()) {
                // Copy into structs
                for (std::size_t i{}; i < data.size(); ++i) 
                    data[i].xyz.push_back({ indicator, xyz[i].x, xyz[i].y,xyz[i].z });
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "\n***Error: Mismatch in number of xyz and modes\n\n";
                parsingOKsoFar = false;
            }
        }
        else 
            std::cerr << "\n***Error: Could not read XYZ\n\n";
    }
    return data;
}

int main() {
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ "r:\\data.txt" }; ifs) {
        std::vector data = readData(ifs);
        for (const Data& d : data) {
            std::cout << "\n\n\n----------------------\nMode:\t" << d.ID << "\nFrequency:\t" << d.frequency << "\nForce Cnst:\t" << d.forceCnst
                << "\nRed. Mass:\t" << d.redMass << "\nIR Active:\t" << (d.irActive ? "YES"s : "NO"s)
                << "\nIR Intens:\t" << d.irIntensity << "\nRaman Active:\t" << (d.ramanActive ? "YES"s : "NO"s) << '\n';
            for (const XYZ& xyz : d.xyz)
                std::cout << "\nX:\t\t" << xyz.x << "\nY:\t\t" << xyz.y << "\nZ:\t\t" << xyz.z << '\n';

        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\n***Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```